# jqxgrid export to PDF in Firefox: long data in a column to runover next columns

Tags: jsfiddle, jqxgrid, export-to-pdf, jqwidget

I'm using jqxgrid from jQWidgets to display some data. When I export my grid data to PDF using Firefox, if the data in a cell is too long, it will ram all over next couple columns like [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HUlZ.png). This doesn't happen in Chrome or Safari though.

I asked on jQWidgets forum but seems like it'll take them sometimes, it will probably take them a month or so to reply. I can even replicate this behavior using their [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cymb54r/6/)

```
$("#pdfExport").click(function () {
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'pdf', 'jqxGrid');
```

});

by copying "Caffe Espresso Caffe" and pasting it a couple times to produce a long string, then export to PDF using Firefox browser.

It seems like jQWidgets problem to me. But I'm wondering if anyone encounter this too ? is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) released a new version 2 days ago so this seems to work now. Hope this information help you.

Comment: They did include this bug to the fix in v4.0.0. Thanks :D